# Shadow to current box showing

Tags: jquery, for-loop, canvas

i already put the ctx to shadowColor = "white"; when the button click and remove it when i create boxes. however , i want to remove the shadow color of the first box when the second red box appear and the shadow should be applied only to second box. it should be like when they click the button the first box will be red with shadow and then later will go to the second box. the second box will turn red with shadow while the first box will be back to gray background color but without shadow. Kindly help. Thank you..

You can access the code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-kare-hwkq2?file=/index.html:0-2151

```js
  var data = [
      {
        name: "1",
        x: 20,
        y: 21,
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        bgColor: "#00FF00",
        radius: 2,
        version: "1.0.0"
      },
      // for horizontal
      {
        name: "5",
        x: 110,
        y: 21,
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        bgColor: "#00FF00",
        radius: 2
      },
      {
        name: "6",
        x: 200,
        y: 21,
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        bgColor: "#00FF00",
        radius: 2
      }
    ];
    var c = document.getElementById("NodeList");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

    // set initial blur of 3px
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // loop through the data array
      const _data = data[i];
      ctx.beginPath(); // Call beginPath before drawing any shape
      ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
      ctx.fillRect(_data.x, _data.y, _data.width, _data.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";

      ctx.stroke();
    }
    $("#k").click(function () {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const _data = data[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        //ctx.shadowColor = "gray";
        setTimeout(function () {
          if (i != 0) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
            ctx.shadowColor = "#0f172b";
            ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
            ctx.fillRect(
              data[i - 1].x,
              data[i - 1].y,
              data[i - 1].width,
              data[i - 1].height
            );
            ctx.fill();
          }
          ctx.shadowColor = "white";
          ctx.shadowBlur = 25;
          ctx.fillStyle = "red";
          ctx.fillRect(_data.x, _data.y, _data.width, _data.height);
          ctx.fill();
        }, 2000 * i);
      }
    });
```

```css
body { background: #0f172b; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="NodeList" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
<button id="k">Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear all and redraw all, at every frame, always.

Then, you can define a simple `draw()` function, that you will call at every frame. This drawing function should be the most state-agnostic as possible, so that you can handle changing the states outside of it, and it will render correctly.

Here it's a simple matter of setting the context's style when drawing the highlighted shape, i.e it's just a matter of marking which shape is highlighted.

```js
var data = [
  {
    x: 20,
    y: 21,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
  },
  // for horizontal
  {
    x: 110,
    y: 21,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
  },
  {
    x: 200,
    y: 21,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
  }
];
var c = document.getElementById("NodeList");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

let highlighted = -1; // the index of the shape we want to highlight
// a single function to draw every frame
function draw() {
  // clear all
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  // redraw all
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // loop through the data array
    const _data = data[i];
    const is_highlighted = i === highlighted;
    // set the context's style depending on if we are highlighted or not
    ctx.fillStyle = is_highlighted ? "red" : "gray";
    ctx.shadowColor = is_highlighted ? "white" : "transparent";
    ctx.shadowBlur = is_highlighted ? 25 : 0;
    // fillRect doesn't need beginPath()
    ctx.fillRect(_data.x, _data.y, _data.width, _data.height);
  }
}
$("#k").click(function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      highlighted = i;
      draw();
    }, 2000 * i);
  }
});
// initial all gray
// highlighted is currently -1, which points to no shape
draw();
```

```css
body { background: #0f172b; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="NodeList" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
<button id="k">Hello</button>
```